# Run the example of help(np.frombuffer) and got the error like this: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__buffer__'`,why?

Tags: python, numpy

Here is an example of help(np.frombuffer):

```
s = 'hello world'
np.frombuffer(s, dtype='S1', count=5, offset=6)
```

help(np.frombuffer)'s output like this:

```
array(['w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'],dtype='|S1')
```

However, I got the error like this:

```
s = 'hello world'
np.frombuffer(s, dtype='S1', count=5, offset=6)

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<ipython-input-151-624044df0072>", line 1, in <module>
     np.frombuffer(s, dtype='S1', count=5, offset=6)
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__buffer__'`
```

Could you tell me why the example of help(np.frombuffer) not run ok?

Run on Spyder(Python3.6)'s IPython console.

Comment: Thanks for the answer link. It's helpful!

Answer (score 1):

this is a python 2.7 example - it works. tested it in `www.pyfiddle.io`:

[image]

If you are using 3.6 you should move to some tutorals for 3.6 or you will run into issues along your way all the time.

You can review the details of changelogs on https://docs.python.org/3/